# ExpressJS - Auto Compiling CoffeeScript For Front End

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

Node.js is simply awesome. And it seems as though Express.js is the Sinatra of Ruby for Node.js.

I love how simple Express is. To make things better, I configured it to use CoffeeScript in the backend. I am wondering if there is a way to use auto compile and serve coffeescript files.

Currently I am writing them in a public `src` folder, and compiling it to a `lib` folder. I would like some thing a little simpler.

Some thing like 
`[server]/coffee/file.js` -> will provide the compled source of `[server]/coffee/file.coffee`?

I found a package, `express-coffee` which is as old as Node I guess and not updated in 2 years :(.

Is there any specific way to compile front end coffee script to JS without manual interaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [connect-coffee-script](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-connect-coffee-script). And this how I use it (in coffeescript) :

```
app.use require('connect-coffee-script')
    src    : "#{__dirname}/client/assets/coffee"
    dest   : "#{__dirname}/client/public/js"
    prefix : '/js'
```

Comment: Is this happening real time? I am expecting to use Heroku. I red some where about compiling things on deployment which is good.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [coffee-middleware](https://npmjs.org/package/coffee-middleware) (or similar) and you can process browser requests for `.js` files, locate the corresponding `.coffee` files on the server's filesystem, transpile them to javascript, and sent the javascript code down to the browser.